# R error: regular expression is invalid in this locale

Tags: r

I am trying to gather all instances of "Walloni\xeb" within a data-frame column in order to remove "\" using the grep function. However, I'm getting the following error message as shown below:

```
grep("Walloni\xeb", InvoAndinfo2$Regio)

Error in grep("Walloni\xeb", InvoAndinfo2$Regio) :
regular expression is invalid in this locale
```

Does anyone know what to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash is a special character in `regexp`, if you want to look for a string that has a backslash, you should escape it by adding another backslah in front of it.

Try:

`grep("Walloni\\xeb", InvoAndinfo2$Regio)`